# Using jQuery to make checkboxes like radio how can I uncheck? fiddle included

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm using this code to make checkboxes act like radio buttons. What can I add/change so when a checked box is clicked on it'll uncheck?

http://jsfiddle.net/peter/4Awf9/

```
$(".radiounique").click(function() {
$(".radiounique").removeAttr('checked');
$(this).attr('checked', true);
});

<input type="checkbox" class="radiounique" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="radiounique" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="radiounique" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="radiounique" value="1">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to act like the radiobuttons -

can try -

```
$(".radiounique").click(function() {
    var state = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(".radiounique").removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', state );
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4Awf9/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake. Radiobuttons are radiobuttons, checkboxes are checkboxes. Do not confuse your users by changing a checkbox list function to emulate a radiobutton list. That is very bad practice.

By the way, if you disable javascript it still will be possible to check multiple boxes.

I know this is not the answer you would like, but it's the truth.

Comment: I agree. There's no reason to not stick to standardized UI in this case. Even cosmetically, I don't see how "check one option" (fake radio with checkboxes) is a must-have versus "choose one option" (real radio)

Comment: I understand that, but when all our tables on our site have the first column as a checkbox and one of them must restrict users to selected one row only it's just how I decided to do it for design reasons. Users cannot login without JS enabled, and there is also server side validation that only one row ID is being submitted.

Comment: Curious to know what your methods would be for this... If users check one row in a table then click a button to execute an action. While I could put radio buttons in a column instead of checkboxes, I could also add a button into each row to let them click and run the action. Design wise I don't like seeing a bunch of buttons down a column. What other options are there?

Comment: honestly, it depends on how your website looks. personally I'd go for a button or an image with a url with some JS to make it work as a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".radiounique").click(function() {

        var clicked = $(this);

        $(".radiounique").each(function(){
            if($(clicked[0]).attr('value') != $(this).attr('value'))
                 $(this).attr('checked', false);     
        })

    if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
            $(this).attr('checked', true);

});
```